# Spring : Loading Properties from Database and local files

Tags: spring

I am trying to load properties from database. I got successful in that.
But now problem is that, for dataSource bean, i want to use placeholders. 
Please see applicationProperties.xml file, then one can get idea:

```
<!-- Data Source Bean -->
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${password}" />
</bean>

<!-- My Own class for managing properites came from Database -->
<bean class="PropFromDB.PropFromDB.PropertiesUtil" >
    <property name="propertiesArray">
        <list>
            <ref bean="propertiesFromDB" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- PropertiesFactoryBean bean -->
<bean id="propertiesFromDB"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="properties" ref="commonsConfigurationFactoryBean" />
</bean>

<!-- CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean bean -->
<bean id="commonsConfigurationFactoryBean"
        class="org.springmodules.commons.configuration.CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean">
    <constructor-arg ref="databaseConfiguration"></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- DatabaseConfiguration bean -->
<bean name="databaseConfiguration" 
    class="org.apache.commons.configuration.DatabaseConfiguration">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="dataSource" />
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="properties" />
    <constructor-arg index="2" value="key" />
    <constructor-arg index="3" value="value" />
</bean>
```

The above code is for loading properties from DB. now as you can see for dataSource bean, there are some placeholders used. So i included this line at top:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:databaseForConfiguration.properties"/>
```

databaseForConfiguration.properties **contains all required properties** and **is in classpath** :

```
driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
username=user
password=pass
```

But when i try to execute, i get following exception:

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [${driverClassName}]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:62)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1489)
    ... 60 more
```

and similar for **{url}**, **{username}**,**{password}**.

As it's simple to understand, that for PropertiesUtil bean to initialize, first dataSource bean need to initialize. And for dataSource bean, local properties placeholders must be there. **Which in this case, not getting.**

I want **both these things**, **load placeholders from local files** and **also from database**.

Anyone please help me to resolve this problem.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

For

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${password}" />
</bean>
```

I created factory for datasource. and now it's look like this:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="core.factory.DataSourceFactory" factory-method="createDataSource">
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="DBConfig.properties" />
     </bean>
```

The DataSourceFactory class look like this:

```
public class DataSourceFactory
{

    private static final String DRIVER_CLASS_NAME = "db.driver";
    private static final String URL = "db.url";
    private static final String URL_LOGDB = "logdb.url";
    private static final String USER_NAME = "db.username";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "db.password";

    public static DataSource createDataSource(String propertyFilename) throws IOException
    {
        Properties properties = getProperties(propertyFilename);
        return getDataSource(URL, properties);
    }

    public static DataSource createDataSourceForLogDb(String propertyFilename) throws Exception
    {
        Properties properties = getProperties(propertyFilename);
        return getDataSource(URL_LOGDB, properties);
    }

    private static Properties getProperties(final String fileName) throws IOException
    {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        InputStream in = DataSourceFactory.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
        properties.load(in);
        in.close();
        return properties;
    }

    private static DataSource getDataSource(final String url, final Properties properties)
    {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(properties.getProperty(DRIVER_CLASS_NAME));
        dataSource.setUrl(properties.getProperty(url));
        dataSource.setUsername(properties.getProperty(USER_NAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(properties.getProperty(PASSWORD));
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Now i am able to get properties from local file as well as database, too.

Regarding another problem i put in comments, which was to load i18n resources from database,i got solution from this link: [Spring MVC: Database MessageSource fall back to properties file](http://blog.mornati.net/spring-mvc-database-messagesource-fall-back-to-properties-file/).

I myself posted question and now i got solution.
Hope this will be useful for someone.

Comment: Hello @Jaydeep.. Its a great solution you posted. Any place that we can find full source code. It would be a great help....

Answer (score 6):

First of all you missunderstood `<context:property-placeholder>`. Its `location` is for `file`, not `Properties` object.

Right, your `databaseForConfiguration.properties` contains a `Properties` object from DB, but it isn't a `.properties` file.

So, try this:

```
<bean id="myProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean"
      p:staticMethod="org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationConverter.getProperties"
      p:arguments-ref="databaseConfiguration"/>

<context:property-placeholder properties-ref="myProperties"/>
```

From other side it isn't clear how you are going to load properties from DB, if you try to use `placeholders` for `DataSource` options. In this case you already should already have a configured `<context:property-placeholder>`...

**UPDATE**

There is reason to mix several answers from different topics. Asn I've shown above the `MethodInvokingFactoryBean` does the stuff to build `Properties` object.

If your `<context:property-placeholder>` can't resolve placeholders (`Could not load JDBC driver class [${driverClassName}]`), then it doesn't see your `databaseForConfiguration.properties` in the classpath.

Be sure to use correct `location` value, e.g. `location="classpath:WEB-INF/databaseForConfiguration.properties"`, if your file is there with WAR.

Comment: No. Sorry. you misunderstood. databaseForConfiguration.properties is properties file.(I now edited above question, you can see). For loading properties from db, i have mixed up logic from several sites. like first i got help from [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28893/Loading-Application-Properties-from-a-Database). than for exposing properties to java class, i referred [link](http://codingbone.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/how-to-load-properties-files-into-spring-and-expose-to-the-java-classes/)

Comment: Thanks for correction (+1). I've updated my answer according that new info.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. This would might help others. I also get knowledge. but my problem is difficult to explain, but now i resolved it in other way. If you have another solution to load properties from database, please provide. I want to apply i18n and for this as you know properties files is needed. So instead of file, i want to load from database. So how can i load i18n properties from database? how my database table structure should be ? thanks in advance.